# Adding external pdf content generated from SVG using apache batik to Source PDF using Itext with header and footer

Tags: pdf, svg, itext, itext7, batik

I have the below requirement.

- Convert the SVG to PDF using Apache batik
- Prepare source PDF document with Header and Footer using IText 7
- Take the converted PDF and embed it in the content of the source PDF

I have seen IText supports converting an SVG to Image but the output is not proper. The output from batik seems to be perfect.

Below is my code. Can anyone please suggest a proper approach ? I am not able to achieve it

**SVG to PDF using batik**

```
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(Paths.get("Input").toAbsolutePath()+"/test.svg"));
               byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
               FileOutputStream pdfOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(Paths.get("Output").toAbsolutePath()+"/convertedSvg.pdf"));
               Transcoder transcoder = new PDFTranscoder();
               TranscoderInput transcoderInput = new TranscoderInput(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
               TranscoderOutput transcoderOutput = new TranscoderOutput(pdfOutputStream);
               int dpi = 300;
               transcoder.addTranscodingHint(PDFTranscoder.KEY_WIDTH, new Float(dpi * 29.7));
               transcoder.addTranscodingHint(PDFTranscoder.KEY_HEIGHT, new Float(dpi * 42.0));
               transcoder.addTranscodingHint(PDFTranscoder.KEY_PIXEL_UNIT_TO_MILLIMETER,(25.4f / 72f));
               transcoder.transcode(transcoderInput, transcoderOutput);
```

**iText Code**

```
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File(Paths.get("Output").toAbsolutePath()+"/final.pdf")));
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);    
pdfDoc.setDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A3.rotate());
NormalPageHeader headerHandler = new NormalPageHeader(Paths.get("images").toAbsolutePath() + "\\logo.png", pdfFontMap);
pdfDoc.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.START_PAGE, headerHandler);
PageEndEvent pageEndEvent = new PageEndEvent(Paths.get("images").toAbsolutePath() + "\\FooterLineExternal.png" ,pdfFontMap);
pdfDoc.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, pageEndEvent);
Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);
doc.getPageEffectiveArea(PageSize.A3.rotate());
Table imageTable = new Table(1);
imageTable.setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
imageTable.setWidth(UnitValue.createPercentValue(100));
Cell cell = new Cell();
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("Horizontal Trajectory");
paragraph.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.TOP);
cell.add(paragraph);
cell.setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
cell.setPaddingTop(50);
imageTable.addCell(cell);
doc.add(imageTable);
doc.close();
```

Comment: Could you share the pdfs and explain what is wrong and what is expected?

Comment: Hi, Itext has a feature to Convert svg to image. The image generated from Itext is not of high quality. I should be able to search for some texts in the output. For this,  I want to convert svg to pdf using batik and embed this pdf in another source PDF without overlapping header and footer.

Comment: Could you share the svg, so that the can see what iText does wrong and whether there is any way to fix it

Comment: Unfortunately, i am not allowed to share the SVG data as it is confidential. Apologies !